# How to match String with Pattern in Groovy

Tags: regex, string, groovy, gradle, match

I am trying to decide whether a simple regular expression matches a string in Groovy. Here's my task in gradle. I tried to match with 2 different ways I found on the net, but neither of them works. It always prints out "NO ERROR FOUND"

```
task aaa << {
    String stdoutStr = "bla bla errors found:\nhehe Aborting now\n hehe"
    println stdoutStr
    Pattern errorPattern = ~/error/
//  if (errorPattern.matcher(stdoutStr).matches()) {
    if (stdoutStr.matches(errorPattern)) {
        println "ERROR FOUND"
        throw new GradleException("Error in propel: " + stdoutStr)
    } else {
        println "NO ERROR FOUND"
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `String.contains` suffice?

Comment: In my real code I use a regular expression like: /(?i)error|fail|abort/, I'm not sure if contains works with Patters. If it does, then it would be a good solution

Comment: Nah, i thought it was just the `error` case :-)

Comment: Agree the sample code didn't make clear OP wanted to use the matched substring data. I also like `String.startsWith()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(?s)` ignores line breaks for `.*` (DOTALL) and the regexp there means a full match.  so with `==~` as shortcut it's:

```
if ("bla bla errors found:\nhehe Aborting now\n hehe" ==~ /(?s).*errors.*/) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (errorPattern.matcher(stdoutStr).matches()) {
```

The `matches()` method requires the whole string to match the pattern, if you want to look for matching substrings use `find()` instead (or just `if(errorPattern.matcher(stdoutStr))` since Groovy coerces a Matcher to Boolean by calling `find`).